# pandas frequency of a specific value per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have data for 50K shoppers and the products they bought. I want to count the number of times each user purchased product "a". `value_counts` seems to be the fastest way to calculate these types of numbers for a grouped pandas data frame. However, I was surprised at how much slower it was to calculate the purchase frequency for just one specific product (e.g., "a") using `agg` or `apply`. I could select a specific column from a data frame created using `value_counts` but that could be rather inefficient on very large data sets with lots of products.

Below a simulated example where each customer purchases 10 times from a set of three products. At this size you already notice speed differences between `apply` and `agg` compared to `value_counts`. Is there a better/faster way to extract information like this from a grouped pandas data frame?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [f'c{j}' for i in range(10) for j in range(50000)],
    "col2": np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c"], size=500000, replace=True)
})
dfg = df.groupby("col1")

# value_counts is fast
dfg["col2"].value_counts().unstack()

# apply and agg are (much) slower
dfg["col2"].apply(lambda x: (x == "a").sum())
dfg["col2"].agg(lambda x: (x == "a").sum())

# much faster to do
dfg["col2"].value_counts().unstack()["a"]
```

EDIT:

Two great responses to this question. **Given the starting point of an already grouped data frame**, it seems there may not be a better/faster way to count the number of occurrences of a single level in a categorical variable than using (1) `apply` or `agg` with a lambda function or (2) using `value_counts` to get the counts for all levels and then selecting the one you need.

The `groupby`/`size` approach is an excellent alternative to `value_counts`. With a minor edit to Cainã Max Couto-Silva's answer, this would give:

```
dfg = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])
dfg.size().unstack(fill_value=0)["a"]
```

I assume there would be a trade-off at some point where if you have many levels `apply`/`agg` or `value_counts` on an already grouped data frame may be faster than the `groupby`/`size` approach which requires creating a newly grouped data frame. I'll post back when I have some time to look into that.

Thanks for the comments and answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still faster:

```py
dfg = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])
dfg.size().unstack()
```

---

**Tests:**

```
%%timeit
pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)
# > 712 ms ± 12.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
dfg = df.groupby("col1")
dfg["col2"].value_counts().unstack()
# > 165 ms ± 12.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
dfg = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])
dfg.size().unstack()
# > 131 ms ± 1.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

If we expand the dataframe to **5 million rows**:

```py
df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(10)])

print(f'df.shape = {df.shape}')
# > df.shape = (5000000, 2)

print(f'{df.shape[0]:,} rows.')
# > 5,000,000 rows.
```

```
%%timeit
pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)
# > 1.58 s ± 33.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
dfg = df.groupby("col1")
dfg["col2"].value_counts().unstack()
# > 1.27 s ± 47.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
dfg = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])
dfg.size().unstack()
# > 847 ms ± 53.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: crosstab scales well. Try this test with larger data, say 10k rows.

Comment: Actually, the original `df` tested from the question example has 500k rows. If I append it to itself, leaving it with 1 million rows, the results don't change much. Same pattern.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I've expanded a bit more (5M rows) (see update), and it seems that the difference between `pd.crosstab` and the `value_counts` approach gets smaller. Nonetheless, the pattern remains. I'm using a standard laptop.

Comment: Ok, thanks for testing. I assumed the timings were for sample data

Answer (score 2):

Filter before `value_counts`

```
df.loc[df.col2=='a','col1'].value_counts()['c0']
```

Also I think `crosstab` is 'faster' than `groupby` + `value_counts`

```
pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)
```

Comment: Doubt it. Crosstab is based on pivot table, which is slow compared to groupby. I believe if you want convenience then crosstab/pivot table. If you want more speed, then you may have to do more work with groupby

Comment: @sammywemmy the groupby is fast but chain with unstack may not